# Integrated H-Bridge (ST VNH3SP30-E) suitable for low-side current-sensing?

Tags: sensor, current-measurement, h-bridge

For motor control, I need to monitor its current. Can a simple low side shunt be used for measurement, or will the offset voltage (no direct GND connection) cause problems?

http://www.st.com/internet/automotive/subclass/1039.jsp

Comment: What current range?

Comment: re: *offset voltage (no direct GND connection)*.  How is the ground actually connected?  How much offset do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say how much current the motor needs, but because it uses Hall effect instead of a shunt resistor [this sensor (ACS712)](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/0712/0712.pdf) has a very low internal resistance of 1.2 mΩ. That's only 12 mV drop at 10 A. Sensitivity up to 185 mV/A.

[image]

Notice also that the high current path is galvanically isolated from the signal ground in this sensor.  That can solve the ground offset problem.  IP- may be connected to power ground, while GND can be connected to signal ground.  VIOUT will be referenced to GND.